# Function '_fsopen' doesn't work for write in file. C

Tags: c, winapi, io

I have a trouble which i can't to solve, therefore i hope that someone help me.

I wrote my function which open file and checks for errors with this.

```
BOOLEAN openFile(HWND hwnd, FILE **stream, const char *szOpenedFileName, const char *mode)
{
    //errno_t err = fopen_s(&(*stream), szOpenedFileName, mode);
    //errno_t err = _fsopen(szOpenedFileName, mode, _SH_DENYNO); gets err = 13 with write in file   
    //*stream = fopen(szOpenedFileName, mode);
    *stream = _fsopen(szOpenedFileName, mode, _SH_DENYNO);
    if (stream == NULL)
    //if (err)
    {
        char text[512];
        sprintf_s(text, 512, "Не удалось открыть файл \"%s\".", szOpenedFileName);
        MessageBox(hwnd, text, "Ошибка", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

That function good works when i am reading from file, but when i want to write in file, i am getting a trouble which is shown in [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCDjG.png).

Global variables:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
char szOpenedFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";
OPENFILENAME sfn;
char szSavedFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";

FILE *stream;
```

For open file and reading i use

```
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) //Действие, после выбора в диалоговом окне файла для открытия
{                       
  char *fileText;
    char paragraph[512];                        

    if (openFile(hwnd, &stream, szOpenedFileName, "r"))                     
    {                               
      for (unsigned i = 0; fgets(paragraph, 512, stream) != NULL; i++)
        {                           
          if (i == 0)
            {
              // Выделение памяти на 3 байт больше, так как необходимо хранить терминальный символ
                // и добавленные символы "\r"
                fileText = (char*)calloc(strlen(paragraph) + 3, sizeof(char));  
                strcpy_s(fileText, strlen(paragraph) + 1, paragraph);   
                append(fileText, "\r", strlen(fileText) - 1);
            }
            else
            {   
            // Выделение памяти на 4 байта больше, так как необходимо хранить
            // терминальные символы 2-х строк и добавленные символы "\r"
                fileText = (char*)realloc(fileText, strlen(fileText) + strlen(paragraph) + 4);   
                append(paragraph, "\r", strlen(paragraph) - 1);
                append(fileText, paragraph, strlen(fileText));
            }
        }

        SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT, fileText);                                                  
        SetFocus(hEdit);

        free(fileText);
        fclose(stream);
    }                       
}
```

For save file and writing i use

```
if (GetSaveFileName(&sfn))
{
  HANDLE hFile;                         

    hFile = CreateFile(szSavedFileName, GENERIC_WRITE,        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

  if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
      DWORD dwTextLength;

      dwTextLength = GetWindowTextLength(hEdit);
        //Если есть, что сохранять
        if (dwTextLength > 0)
        {
          if (openFile(hwnd, &stream, szSavedFileName, "w"))
            {       
            char *editText;

                editText = (char*)calloc(dwTextLength + 1, 1);
                GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT, editText, dwTextLength + 1);
                fwrite(editText, 1, sizeof(editText), stream);

                free(editText);
                fclose(stream);
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    else
    {
      char text[512];
        sprintf_s(text, 512, "Не удалось создать файл \"%s\".", szSavedFileName);
        MessageBox(hwnd, text, "Ошибка", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C, please tag only **one** language.

Comment: It just tells you that you can't open the file because another process already has the file opened.  And it denied write sharing.  Nothing unusual about it.  It does look like you don't understand how fsopen() works.  Using SH_DENYNO is pointless, you might as well use fopen().  It is not made to give you a backdoor to open a file that another process has already opened.  When it demands "don't write!" then the OS ensures that nobody can.  Pretty essential, without such a guarantee the file content will just be a random mix of output from two programs that nobody can read correctly.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you've already opened it with `CreateFile`.

Comment: for what you call `openFile` when you already open file with `CreateFile` ?

Comment: Thou shalt not use ANSI character encoding. Ever. [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays in that `_fsopen` method fails. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx):

> Each of these functions returns a pointer to the stream. A null pointer value indicates an error.
>
> [..]
>
> If execution is allowed to continue, these functions return NULL and set errno to EINVAL.

Make sure to check `errno` and see what the underlying error is.

Moreover, **please notice** that you are not checking the actual return value:

```
*stream = _fsopen(szOpenedFileName, mode, _SH_DENYNO);
if (stream == NULL)
```

You assign the value to `*stream`, but check `stream`. The file fails to open with write privileges, but you never notice because of this.